# How to use the tab key in google app scripts HTML development

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

when editing an HTML file using the google app scripts, pressing the tab key does not indent anything past a couple of spaces.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question was asked on: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95946/how-to-apply-autoformatting-in-google-apps-script

As mentioned in the about link, Google App Script does not have auto-formatting features. You can press Shift+Tab to auto indent your code. Another option is to use an external JavaScript formatting service such as: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: hmm interesting shift tab doesn't seem  to work if the line hasn't been indented before, only if I first space it, then delete it, then tab it. Is there any way to use some external editor to connect with google apps script editor? Like is there some kind of API to run functions etc or does it have to be through their editor?

Comment: As mentioned in the link, you need to select all the text first using Cntrl+A. If that does not work for you, then you can simply copy and past the code to http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: interesting, I tried that, but it only works within .gs files but not .html files.. I would prefer not to copy and paste the code, do you kow if there is some kind of API that can do the same as the default editr?

Answer (score 0):

The third button on the Google Apps Acript editor toolbar called "Indent" does the 'smart' indentation in .gs files.

To better format HTML files you need to click this to turn the auto-indent **off**.  You can then indent code however you like in any file.

I turn if off when working in HTML and often put if back on when working in a .gs file.